# GeoServer/GeoTools ImageMosaic: Create layer with shapefile index as BBOX

Tags: geoserver

I am using the ImageMosaic Plugin to generate a GeoServer layer with spatially sparsely distributed granules (1° x 1° tiffs). Granules have the same crs, but may vary in resolution. The raster tileindex or shapefile index looks as follows:

[image: shapefile index]

The configured GeoServer layer uses an overall Bounding Box (black extent in the figure above) for the granules. Is it possible to configure the layer with the Bounding Boxes of the individual granules which is basically given in the shapefile index (which the GeoServer automatically generates and successfully uses to read the data)?

By using an overall Bounding Box enclosing all granules, I am seeing two issues:

1. As cached layer, empty tiles will be generated in the *empty space* instead of *out of range*
2. GetFeatureInfo requests in the *empty space* return a value instead of *out of range*

I have tried the footprint management using the shapefile index also as footprints.shp but this is for something else.

EDIT
Seems that Request Filter is one solution which can be implemented on the server-side (https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/layers/requestfilters.html). However, there is hardly any documentation on how to implement this (especially if you are using the integrated GeoWebCache (within GeoServer) rather than the stand-alone one).

I generated a tiff mask (boolean, 1 data/0 nodata) from the shapefile index with `gdal_rasterize`. Afterwards, I tried to add a request filter to my cached GeoServer layer via REST.

```xml
 <GeoServerLayer>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <inMemoryCached>true</inMemoryCached>
  <name>layername</name>
  <mimeFormats><string>image/png8</string></mimeFormats>
  <gridSubsets>
   <gridSubset>
    <gridSetName>EPSG:4326</gridSetName>
   </gridSubset>
  </gridSubsets>
  <metaWidthHeight>
   <int>4</int>
   <int>4</int>
  </metaWidthHeight>
  <expireCache>0</expireCache>
  <expireClients>0</expireClients>
  <requestFilters>
   <fileRasterFilter>
    <name>testfilter</name>
    <zoomStop>12</zoomStop>
    <storagePath>/path/to/tifmask</storagePath>
    <fileExtension>tif</fileExtension>
   </fileRasterFilter>
  </requestFilters>
  <parameterFilters>
   <styleParameterFilter>
    <key>STYLES</key>
    <defaultStyle></defaultStyle>
   </styleParameterFilter>
  </parameterFilters>
  <gutter>0</gutter>
 </GeoServerLayer>
```

But the Request Filter is not added to the layer. I understand that there is a difference between GeoServerLayer (GeoServer) and wmsLayer (GeoWebCache), but by adding a GeoServerLayer it will add it to GeoWebCache as well. Is the Request Filter not recognized by Geoserver?

Comment: I think by https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/configuration.html and https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/tutorial.html#data-imagemosaic-tutorial that sparse data is supposed to work somehow. The empty corners in the example mosaics present your case. The layer in WMS and WCS has one bounding box. More accurate index handling on the client side can be implemented for example by publishing the granule index as a vector layer with WFS.

Comment: Thanks @user30184, appreciate it. Yes, I've read these documents. Just to clarify, it is working but it comes with the mentioned drawbacks. I wanted to check if there is something I can do from the geoserver-side (maybe I'm missing some special configurations). Regarding the client-side, that's what I was doing for another project. Using `ogr2ogr` to dissolve the granule features and publish it as WFS. Then get the feature geometry coordinates as json and use that as boundary in the `L.TileLayer.BoundaryCanvas` plugin ([link](https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas)).